# How to have a fallback image for flutter_svg network image in Flutter (SvgPicture.network)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I'm calling an SvgPicture network image as so:

```
SvgPicture.network(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Circle-icons-image.svg",
        width: 90,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
```

However, what if the URL is malformed? How can I have a fallback image if this happens so my whole app doesn't crash?

I've tried to wrap this with a try/catch as so, but to no avail as the crash still kills the app.

```
SvgPicture getImageType(String? imageUrl) {
    try {
      return SvgPicture.network(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/malformed_url.svg",
        width: 90,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    } catch (_) {
      return SvgPicture.network(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Circle-icons-image.svg",
        width: 90,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the resource exists using the `http` package. If it doesn't exist, use the other URL:

```
var image = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/malformed_url.svg';
final response =
  await http.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/malformed_url.svg');

if (response.status != 200) {
 image = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Circle-icons-image.svg'
}
```

You can check if the SVG is malformed by checking if flutter_svg can parse it:

```
final SvgParser parser = SvgParser();
try {
  parser.parse(svgString, warningsAsErrors: true);
  print('SVG is supported');
} catch (e) {
  print('SVG contains unsupported features');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a good idea if the image URL doesn't exist, but is there a more generic way? Imagine another exception occurring (a malformed SVG for example or an unsupported SVG), I would like for the app to fallback to a hardcoded image.